# ReplayKit doesn't rotate

Tags: ios, replaykit

When trying to record the screen with **RPScreenRecorder** there's an **issue** when trying to **rotate the device**, the device orientation is not changing while the screen recorder is active. After the screen recorder stops, the orientation changes works again.

We have tried to find a work around calculating the position of the device with the gravity vector (from Core Motion device motion) and it returns the correct orientation but we haven't managed to rotate the screen to that obtained orientation

STEPS TO REPRODUCE

1. Initiate an RPScreenRecorder with the start capture method on a view controller that allows rotations
2. Rotate the device from portrait up position to landscape right or left position
3. Rotation is blocked

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?